# Java objects instanceof

Tags: java, object, instanceof

The instructions say:
Create an equals method that takes an object reference and returns true if the given object equals this object.
 * Hint: You'll need 'instanceof' and cast to a (Position)

I have:

```
class Position {

    private double x,y;
    private int id;

public boolean instanceOf(Object a)
    {
        boolean isInstance;
        if ((Position)a instanceof Position)
            isInstance=true;
        else
            isInstance=false;
        return isInstance;
    }
```

But I'm doing it wrong, and I dont know what my problem is. I'm new to objects so this is kind of confusing me..

Comment: Your given instructions have a faulty hint: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a homework question, I won't give a detail answer.
You have to implement a `equals()` method, not a `instanceOf()` method.  I think this link  help:

- http://www.ibiblio.org/java/course/week4/37.html
- http://www.billthelizard.blogspot.com/2008/08/implementing-equals-in-java.html

The code example in them should be sufficient. Ask again if you need more hint.

Comment: Hmm ok so the only thing I'm missing is this line in their example: Car c = (Car) o; How would I implement this in my case?

Comment: Ok your second link helped. However, I'm confused about this line:if(this == obj)....what exactly does that do, whats 'this' in this case?

Comment: @fprime:  the `if(this == obj)` is just an optimization. it still works without this line.

Comment: You need to override equals - and - hashCode() .. Since this is homework, next problem may related to hashCode() :) – StackTrace 9 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

He clearly said create an `equals()` method, and you got it right here as well. But even after all this you created a method named `instanceOf()`. Why?

Moreover, you may get a [ClassCastException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) on this line, in case some other type of object is passed.

```
    if ((Position)a instanceof Position)
```

Which means, precisely, that you should only cast the `object` to `Position`, after making sure that the `object` passed is of type `Position`. Which means now its good to go further with comparison. If its not of type `Position` in the first place, then why should you bother comparing it further. Because it can never be equal. I hope you are getting my point.

**[Edited to answer the question in comment]**

Well, the actual instance should be of type Position. Once we know that its of type Position using instanceof operator, we know its safe to cast it to type Position from type Object. Now the question is why we need to cast? Because initially the instance was of type Object, and we were not sure about the actual type. You might already know that in Java you can assign any type to Object type, because Object is a parent of every class in Java. Hence, before applying instanceof we were not sure about the type of instance.

In case, you don't cast it, you will never be able to access its properties, namely, x, y, and id. You can try accessing any of these on actual object without casting. You will know you can't. Hence, you can't compare those either. I hope, this made it clear.

Comment: So if it is of type Position, why do I have to cast it into type Position?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the `Object a` is of a `Position` type, but it is defined as `Object` type. In order to access the properties of `Position a`, we have to cast `Object a` to `Position p` using

```
Position p = (Position)a;
```