# instanceof Vs getClass( )

Tags: java, class, instanceof

I see gain in performance when using `getClass()` and `==` operator over `instanceOf` operator.

```
Object  str = new Integer("2000");

long starttime = System.nanoTime();

if(str instanceof String) {
    System.out.println("its string");
} else {
    if (str instanceof Integer) {
        System.out.println("its integer");

    }
}

System.out.println((System.nanoTime()-starttime));

starttime = System.nanoTime();

if(str.getClass() == String.class) {
    System.out.println("its string in equals");
} else {
    if(str.getClass() == Integer.class) {
        System.out.println("its integer");
    }
}

System.out.println((System.nanoTime()-starttime));
```

Is there any guideline, which one to use `getClass()` or `instanceOf`?

Given a scenario: I know exact classes to be matched, that is `String`, `Integer` (these are final classes), etc.

Is using `instanceOf` operator bad practise ?

Comment: This is explained in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals.

Comment: Your timing method is causing artificial delays and producing incorrect timing results. Swap the order you do the checks and you'll see the first check you do (either == or instanceof) will always be longer. I'd guess it's the println()s. You should never include that stuff in your timing block.

Comment: Just one comment apart, to compare performance, use multiple cycle iterations (e.g. 10000) in order to improve accuracy. One single invocation is not a good measure.

Comment: How large is the difference?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

The reason that the performance of `instanceof` and `getClass() == ...` is different is that they are doing different things.

- `instanceof` tests whether the object reference on the left-hand side (LHS) is an instance of the type on the right-hand side (RHS) *or some subtype*.
- `getClass() == ...`  tests whether the types are identical.

So the recommendation is to ignore the performance issue and use the alternative that gives you the answer that you need.

> Is using the `instanceOf` operator bad practice ?

Not necessarily.  Overuse of either `instanceOf` or `getClass()` *may be* "design smell".  If you are not careful, you end up with a design where the addition of new subclasses results in a significant amount of code reworking.  In most situations, the preferred approach is to use polymorphism.

However, there are cases where these are NOT "design smell".  For example, in `equals(Object)` you need to test the actual type of the argument, and return `false` if it doesn't match.  This is best done using `getClass()`.

---

<sup>Terms like "best practice", "bad practice", "design smell", "antipattern" and so on should be used sparingly and treated with suspicion.  They encourage black-or-white thinking.  It is better to make your judgements in context, rather than based purely on dogma; e.g. something that someone said is "best practice".  I recommend that everyone read [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164) if they haven't already done so.</sup>

Answer (score 49):

Do you want to match a class *exactly*, e.g. only matching `FileInputStream` instead of any subclass of `FileInputStream`? If so, use `getClass()` and `==`. I would typically do this in an `equals`, so that an instance of X isn't deemed equal to an instance of a subclass of X - otherwise you can get into tricky symmetry problems. On the other hand, that's more usually useful for comparing that two objects are of the *same* class than of one specific class.

Otherwise, use `instanceof`. Note that with `getClass()` you will need to ensure you have a non-null reference to start with, or you'll get a `NullPointerException`, whereas `instanceof` will just return `false` if the first operand is null.

Personally I'd say `instanceof` is more idiomatic - but using *either* of them extensively is a design smell in most cases.

Answer (score 18):

I know it has been a while since this was asked, but I learned an alternative yesterday

We all know you can do:

```
if(o instanceof String) {   // etc
```

but what if you dont know exactly what type of class it needs to be?
you cannot generically do:

```
if(o instanceof <Class variable>.getClass()) {
```

as it gives a compile error.
Instead, here is an alternative - isAssignableFrom()

For example:

```
public static boolean isASubClass(Class classTypeWeWant, Object objectWeHave) {

    return classTypeWeWant.isAssignableFrom(objectWeHave.getClass())
}
```

Comment: Don't use `isAssignableFrom`. The correct way to write `o instanceof String` using reflection is [`String.getClass().isInstance(o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)). The javadoc even says so: *This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator.*

Answer (score 3):

getClass() has the restriction that objects are only equal to other objects of the same class, the same run time type, as illustrated in the output of below code:

```
class ParentClass{
}
public class SubClass extends ParentClass{
    public static void main(String []args){
        ParentClass parentClassInstance = new ParentClass();
        SubClass subClassInstance = new SubClass();
        if(subClassInstance instanceof ParentClass){
            System.out.println("SubClass extends ParentClass. subClassInstance is instanceof ParentClass");
        }
        if(subClassInstance.getClass() != parentClassInstance.getClass()){
            System.out.println("Different getClass() return results with subClassInstance and parentClassInstance ");
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

SubClass extends ParentClass. subClassInstance is instanceof ParentClass.

Different getClass() return results with subClassInstance and parentClassInstance.