# instanceof vs equals on defined string that identifies the Class

Tags: java

I can test the class type in a program where I'm working both with `instanceof` or getting a field that identifies the class appartenency. so the choice is between

```
if(myObjec instanceof Something){
}
```

And

```
if(myObjec.geClassType().equals("Something")){
}
```

What is the best in terms of efficency?

`geClassType()` is a method present in the object of the program where I'm working(not a standard java method) and is a method that returns a string wih the name of the class. the name is passed as field when the object is created

**EDIT**
the field that I get in the second sample in my code doesn't identify exactly the class but a category and is used also for different routines, but I can use this also for this purpose since I use a specific object for each category. 
So I have reported this as `getClassType` to make my question more clear.

Comment: firstly there is nothing like `geClassType()` secondly `instanceof` is better

Comment: @JigarJoshi there is in the objects of the program where I'm working

Comment: @AndreaF Do you mean `getClass().getName()`?

Comment: @AndreaF ok then it would be compile time check except for subclasses, however I am curious to see what makes you to have such condition in code

Comment: Yuck.  You should avoid writing code that does either!  Wouldn't get past my code review.

Comment: @Amir Afgani read the edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [instanceof Vs getClass( )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989818/instanceof-vs-getclass)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably mean what's the difference if verifying if the object reference belongs to a specific class using `instanceof` vs comparing the name of the class.

`instanceof` works for object references that are from the class or for a subclass of the class being compared. In case of interfaces, it returns `true` if the class (or a super class) of the object reference implements this interface.

`getClass().getName().equals("NameOfTheClass")` (masked by your `getClassType` method) will verify if the class of the object reference is **exactly** from another class, thus a sub class won't pass this test.

Which one to use? Use the one that better suits for your case:

- If you want/need to use object references that belongs to a certain class or interface, despite if the class of the object reference is a subclass or implements the interface, then use `instanceof`. For example, when iterating through the elements of a `Collection` to verify if some objects implement a desired interface.
- If you need to determine if the class of the object reference is **exactly** a specific class, use `getClass().getName().equals("...")`. For example, when implementing `equals` method in a class that should compare to elements that belongs only to this class (no subclasses allowed). Some IDEs do this when auto generating `equals` method.

Still, a better option than `getClass().getName().equals("...")` would be `getClass().equals(TheClass.class)`.

---

In terms of efficiency, if you need to verify if the object belongs to a specific class only, use `getClass().equals(TheClass.class)` rather than `getClass().getName().equals("...")` because one will compare references (which is as fast as `instanceof`). But if you only have the class name, use your current approach. Do not worry about the performance of the application because the JIT will optimize the code at runtime for you after several executions of the code. Still, f you think this statement may be a performance bottleneck, prove it using a profiler.

Comment: I assumed that the behaviour of `instanceof` was what was required since the question specifically referred to efficiency and not functionality - in retrospect perhaps this assumption was incorrect! Re-reading I'm now not quite sure one way or the other if I'm honest.

Comment: @berry120 in performance terms, you should use `getClass().equals(TheClass.class)` rather than `getClass().getName().equals("...")` (but even this is a premature optimization, the JIT may kick the code for you). So, the real question would be: what do you need to compare and why? After answering that, you may choose the preferred option.

Comment: I have added another edit to my question. If I have understood, in my situation should be the same thing `getClass().equals(TheClass.class)` and `if(myObjec.geClassType().equals("Something"))`. If no. Could you give me more details that motivate the best performance of `getClass().equals(TheClass.class)` over `if(myObjec.geClassType().equals("Something"))`?

Answer (score 6):

`instanceof` is more efficient, actually works (since `geClassType()` doesn't exist) and is much more readable.

If `instanceof` is the behaviour that you want (as other answers point out the behaviour is potentially different between the two methods you outline) I'm not sure why you'd even consider the alternative?

EDIT: I should reiterate, even if you have a method in your context that does do what you describe, I still can't see a good reason to do it that way. It may introduce bugs if it doesn't work exactly the way you expect all the time (such as with similarly named classes in different packages), it will likely be slower, but more importantly it's non standard so makes your code much less readable.

**In short, `instanceof` is a useful keyword that does exactly what you want, reliably and readably, with the minimum of fuss. Why on earth wouldn't you use it?!**

Comment: @AndreaF I've edited my answer accordingly - I still can't see a good case for you not using `instanceof` here.

Comment: I don't think the same. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The two may or may not work differently.

```
if(myObjec instanceof Something){ 
}
```

The condition is `true` if `myObjec`'s class, at runtime, is either `Something` or any class derived from `Something`, directly or indirectly.

```
if(myObjec.geClassType().equals("Something")){
}
```

If `geClassType` is a method in `Something` that returns `"Something"`, *and it is not overridden in any subclass*, then this is equivalent to using `instanceof`.  But if there are any subclasses of `Something` that override `geClassType` to return a different string, then `instanceof` would return `true` for objects of that class, while the second would return `false`.

If the two really are equivalent, I don't know which one would be more efficient, and it wouldn't surprise me if the answer varied from one implementation to another.

P.S. I agree with the comment that doing either one of these is probably wrong.  Instead, you should consider how you could arrange the logic inside the curly braces to make it polymorphic; or if there's some property that you're trying to test for that is true of `Something` and false for other classes, then add a polymorphic `boolean isGrungy()` or `boolean hasGrunginess()` method to make it clear what you're trying to test for, instead of relying on the class name.

Answer (score -1):

You probably meant [`getClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

`instanceof` is better because

- `getClass` uses the class name as a `String` which can misspelt and this will never be found out (the equality check will return false),
- `instanceOf` uses the class itself
- The second argument of `instanceof` is checked at compile time, not only for the class name but also for the class hierarchy (for example, "test" isnanceof Integer will get a compile time error).

Comment: `getClass()` will call an object reference of `Class<ObjectClass>` which is already stored by the class loader, it won't make any performance hit and comparing it using `getClass().equals` is as fast as `instanceof` operator. Probably you meant `getClass().getName()` which is slightly slow (seriosuly, 0.0001 ms vs 0.0005 ms won't make a large application choke until dead).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Agreed. Performance wise there may be no difference at all. But in general `instanceof` is better.

Comment: There's no better here. There is a *what do you need*. Refer to my answer for more info.