# Can parent class have class fields of child classes?

Tags: java, inheritance

In my program I have 4 classes zoo, animal, aquatic and flying.

Zoo uses an array of animal class objects. Aquatic and flying extends the animal class.

This is just an example

CLASS FIELDS

ANIMAL

-name

AQUATIC

-environment

FLYING

-number of wings

If I want to print only the flying type.

```
FOR i=0 TO total number of animals CHANGEBY 1
    IF (Animal[i].getEnvironment).equals(land)
        OUTPUT Flying.toString()
```

Can I do something like this?

Comment: Please provide some Java code as example, not just some pseudo-code.

Comment: you need to loop and then check the type via `instanceof` for example.

Comment: Please paste code relevant to fields you are talking about in issue.

Answer (score 0):

> if I want to print only the flying type

Yes, you can do this using `instanceof` operator.

```
if(Animal[i] instanceof Flying){
System.out.println("Ohh Yeah!! I can fly.");
}
```

Note : The above code will print the output if `Animal[i]` passes the `IS-A` `Flying` test; that means `Flying` or it's `subclass` .

OR

```
if(Animal[i].getClass().equals(Flying.class)) {
System.out.println("Ohh Yeah!! I can fly.");
}
```

Note : The above code will print output if and only of `Animal[i]` is `Flying` but **NOT SUBCLASS**.

Comment: `instanceof` and `getClass().equals()` are [not equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989843/2814308). So the first example will print also the subclasses, while the second will not.

Comment: Yes, it will. However, I have just given both the ways it can be checked.

Comment: No, it won't. `x.getClass().equals(Flying.class)` is true only if `x` is of type `Flying`, not of a subclass of it.