# Overriding the equals method that is inherited from Object

Tags: java

I was given the task to override the equals method in java, and I would like to know if the two examples I have provided will accomplish the same thing. If so, what are the differences between them.

```java
public class Animal {

    private int numLegs;

    public Animal(int legs) {
        numLegs = legs;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(other == null) return false;
        if(getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;

        return this.numLegs == ((Animal)other).numLegs;
}
```

```java
public class Animal {

    private int numLegs;

    public Animal(int legs) {
        numLegs = legs;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        //check if other is null first
        if(other == null) return false;
        //Check if other is an instance of Animal or not 
        if(!(other instanceof Animal)) return false;
        //// typecast other to Animal so that we can compare data members
        Animal other = (Animal) other;
        return this.numLegs == other.numLegs;
    }
```

Comment: Did you test the implementations?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989818/instanceof-vs-getclass

Comment: there's a compile error in the second example. You can't create `Animal other` in the `equals` method, since `other` is mentioned in the parameter `Object other`.

Comment: Don't use != to compare objects (in the first example with getClass() != other.getClass()).

Comment: @RalfRenz Would you mind sharing the reason for your suggestion?

Comment: @ernest_k: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java

Comment: @RalfRenz I thought you had a more specific reason. Normally `Class` objects are safe to compare with `==`.

Answer (score 5):

They are not the same.

For the first implementation, you can only return `true` if both of the compared instances belong to the same class (for example, if both are `Cat` instances, assuming `Cat` extends `Animal`).

For the second implementation, you can compare a `Cat` to a `Dog` and still get `true`, since both are instances of `Animal` and have the same number of legs.

They will behave the same if there are no sub-classes of the `Animal` class, since in that case, if `other instanceof Animal` is `true,`getClass() == other.getClass()`is also`true`.

P.S., the second snippet has a typo, since you are re-declaring the `other` variable:

```
Animal other = (Animal) other;
return this.numLegs == other.numLegs;
```

You probably meant to use a different variable name.

Answer (score 2):

They don't do the same thing with subclasses of `Animal`; say if you have a class `Dog` extending `Animal`, and an instance `dog`, calling `animal.equals(dog)` will return `false` with the first version, and `true` with the second.

Answer (score 1):

They are different:

case 1:  This check will always return `true` if the instance belongs to same class like `Cow extends Animal` and `Cat extends Animal`.

Case 2: In this case, if both are the instance of Animal and have same number of legs -- return true.