# How to validate specific subclass?

Tags: java

I have a base class: "Working Items". Witch is extended by 3 subclasses: "Bug", "Story", "Feedback". I receive a command from the console (String), to list all types of Working Items, or one specific type (Bug, Story, Feedback).
I have a collection of type WorkingItems, which contains all of the 3 above mention subclasses. How can I validate while looping the collection if the current object is Bug, Story or Feedback (I can't use instanceof)?

I don't want to divide the collection of Working Items into 3 smaller collections of Bugs, Stories, Feedbacks.

```
private String listAllWorkingItems(StringBuilder result) {
        WIMRepository.getWorkItemList().forEach(workItem -> result.append(workItem.toString()));
        return result.toString();
    }

    private String listAllStories(StringBuilder result) {
        WIMRepository.getWorkItemList(); //TODO
        return result.toString();
    }

    private String listAllBugs(StringBuilder result) {
        WIMRepository.getWorkItemList() //TODO
        return result.toString();
    }

    private String listAllFeedbacks(StringBuilder result) {
        WIMRepository.getWorkItemList() //TODO
        return result.toString();
    }
```

The result should be like this:

Command: show all
Result: "printing working items collection"

Command: show bugs
Result: "printing only the bugs from working items collection"

Comment: Why can't you use `instanceof`? Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, it's a project I need to do.

Comment: What about `.getClass() == Bug.class`?

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to instanceof?

Comment: Not exactly, `instanceof` checks subclasses, checking the class doesn't. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989818/instanceof-vs-getclass. Are you allowed to use `getClass() == ...` then?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't see any point in having 3 subclasses.

```
enum WorkingItemType {
    BUG, STORY, FEEDBACK;
}
class WorkingItem {
    private WorkingItemType type;

    public WorkingItemType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

You didn't show why you've chosen that way, and I am assuming that two classes (`WorkingItem` and `WorkingItemType`) would be enough, which would make the method `listAllBugs` as simple as

```
WIMRepository.getWorkItemList().stream()
        .filter(i -> WorkingItemType.BUG.equals(i.getType()))
        .forEach(i -> result.append(i.toString()));
```

Moreover, one general method would be enough.

```
WIMRepository.getWorkItemList().stream()
        .filter(i -> WorkingItemType.valueOf(input.toUpperCase()).equals(i.getType()))
        .forEach(i -> result.append(i.toString()));
```

`instanceof` is rarely a good choice, so it's nice that the requirements prohibit it.

Comment: The different subclasses (Bug, Story, Feedback) have additional fields that are different, as well as different methods.

Comment: @SAndreev it keeps my answer valid if you add a type field in their base class and will be checking it instead of `instanceof`