# Problem detecting Spinner component

Tags: android, class, components

iterating through a View's components the following code works:

```
if (child.getClass() == EditText.class) {
  ...
} else if (child.getClass() == TextView.class) {
  ...
```

but this doesn't:

```
} else if (child.getClass() == Spinner.class) {
  ...
```

What's the difference between the Spinner class an the other two ?

---

**My mistake ... I was previousy checking if it was a ViewGroup object so It never reached the condition**

Thanks

Comment: Consider using instanceof. It will support subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake ... I was previousy checking if it was a ViewGroup object so It never reached the condition

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(child.getClass() instanceof Spinner.class){
 ...
```

**edit:**

I found Stackoverflow question that explain it:

[Any reason to prefer getClass() over instanceof when generating .equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using

```
if(child instanceof EditText){}
else if(child instanceof TextView){}
else if(child instanceof Spinner){}
```