# Overriding equals() in subclass of class that contains an overridden equals()

Tags: java, equals

I have a `Point` class and a `MinesweeperSquare` class, the latter being a subclass of the former. If I override the `equals` method in the latter, like so:

```
if (!(obj instanceof MinesweeperSquare)) {
  return false;
}
```

FindBugs reports that:

> This class defines an equals method that overrides an equals method in a superclass. Both equals methods
>   methods use `instanceof` in the determination of whether two objects are equal. This is fraught with peril,
>   since it is important that the equals method is symmetrical (in other words, `a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)`).
>   If B is a subtype of A, and A's equals method checks that the argument is an instanceof A, and B's equals method
>   checks that the argument is an instanceof B, it is quite likely that the equivalence relation defined by these
>   methods is not symmetric.

In the `Point` class, I wrote:

```
if (!(obj instanceof Point)) {
  return false;
}
```

How do I write an `equals` method in `MinesweeperSquare` such that the `equals` method is symmetric?

**Update**

FindBugs reports no errors if I write the following in `MinesweeperSquare`:

```
if (o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass()) {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Other answers have already made the right points, but just to help you when searching in the future: it's *overriding*, not *overwriting*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any reason to prefer getClass() over instanceof when generating .equals()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your new method, `MinesweeperSquare.equals(Point)` will always return false, but `Point.equals(MinesweeperSquare)` could return `true`.  Good on you for using FindBugs on this sort of thing.  You might be able to use `getClass()` in both the definition of `Point` and `MinesweeperSquare` to check if the classes are exactly equal...although this, too, is tricky.

Comment: Why would using `getClass()` be tricky? It seems like a good idea.

Comment: "Tricky," meaning, "gratuitous use of reflection."

Answer (score 1):

As you have already cited, if you use 'instanceof' operator in your equals() method implementation it become non-symetric. Get rid of 'instanceof' in your superclass as well as all subclasses and try to override equals() method based on the class properties and common sense. Most IDE's allows you to generate equals() method automatically which is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Using `instanceof` is fine if done correctly, which is quite hard without proper lecture. Using

```
this.getClass().equals(that.getClass())
```

is trivial, but not always does what you need. Look [here](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html) for `canEqual`.

#### EDIT

This all applies only when you control both classes, which doesn't seem to be the case here. So stick with the easy way.