# Java objects are equal though hashcode is different

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

While reading about equals() and hashcode(), I came to know that if two objects are equal, then their hashcodes must be equal, though not vice-versa.

But below example doesn't reflect this.

```
class Employee{

  private String name;

  Employee(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {           
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now if I create two Employee objects as

```
Employee e1 = new Employee("hi");
Employee e2 = new Employee("hi");
```

If i do, `e1.equals(e2)`, it returns **true** even though their hashcodes are different which is evident from printing, `e1.hashcode()` and `e2.hashcode()`.

Can someone explain me?

Comment: The contract on `equals` and `hashCode` must be maintained _by the programmer_; you have not overriden `hashCode` so that it behaves in the desired way. It defaults to the implementation in `Object` which results in the identity hash code.

Comment: Just because, your are checking incorrect implementation

Answer (score 11):

You need to override `hashcode` method and provide implementation which is in contract with equals.

```
   @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode();
    }
```

- if a class overrides `equals`, it must override `hashCode`
- when they are both overridden, `equals` and `hashCode` must `use the same
  set of fields`
- if two objects are `equal`, then their `hashCode` values must be `equal` as
  well
- if the object is `immutable`, then `hashCode` is a candidate for caching
  and `lazy initialization`

You can read about implementing hashcode [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28)

If you don't override the method default behavior will be used from [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) class.

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

Hash based `[HashMap,HashSet,Hashtable,LinkedHashSet,WeakHashMap]` collections will use `hashCode()` to find/store objects in buckets and then they will call `equals()`.

Comment: hi, do you know whether ArrayList.contains follow the contract? Will it check the hash before it check the equal?

Comment: @GMsoF ArrayList contains method does not make use of hashcode(). it only checks equality based on equals().

Answer (score 3):

This is because, everytime you override `equals` method you must also override `hashcode` method.

Else, your objects will be compared according to your code, but their HashCode will be calculated according to the pre-defined algorithm in the Object class.

**NOTE**: - In general, what all parameters you have considered in checking whether your `objects` are equals or not, you should use `all those parameters` to calculate the `hashcodes` for each `object`.

See [this very good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) which describes the use of `equals` and `hashcode` method.

**To quote a line** from this post, that I already described above: -

> **Use same set of fields to compute `hashcode` that you used in `equals` method**

Let's see the below Demo to understand the above statement: -

```
public class Demo {
    private String str;
    private String name;

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // Suppose you compare two objects based on length of their name variable

        // If name equals, object are equal
        if (obj instanceof Demo) {
            return this.name.equals(((Demo)obj).name);
        }
        return false;
    }

    // ****** Badly Overrided hashcode *******
    public int hashcode() {
        // But you calculate hashcode using both the fields

        // You should never use this kind of code in hashcodes. 
        // Use complex algorithm which gives you distinct result for 
        // objects that are not equal.
        return str.length + name.length;
    }
}
```

So, If the two objects have same `name`, then they would be equal, but still if their `str` field has different `length`, then their `hashcodes` will be different.

That is why, you should always use the `same fields` in `equals` and `hashcode` calculation.

Comment: If I am able to compare two objects using equals as shown in the above example, why should I override hashcode method?

Comment: Because hash-based collections (like HashMap and HashSet) use hashCode to first select a bucket, and then compare the argument to every element in the bucket. That's what makes them so efficient: even if the map contains 10000 elements, thanks to the hashCode, the map will only have to compare the argument with 0, 1 or 2 other objects that are in the same bucket.

Comment: @anand. See my edit. The hashcode method of `Object` class, assign the hashcodes based on some algorithm which it uses for `equals` method also.. So, if you change one algorithm , you must change accordingly the other, to make them work in contract.

Comment: @AmitD. That's why I have written there, `Badly Overrided HashCode`.

Comment: better to use getClass than instanceof in equals method

Comment: @anand. `getClass` returns the type of `reference` not the type of `instance`. You need to use `instanceof` here, which checks the actual instance.

Comment: @RohitJain: no. getClass() is a polymorphic method, and returns the actual class of the object.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh. Then is there any valid reason why we should use `instanceof` or `getClass`??

Comment: To make the equals method respect the contract `A.equals(B) iff B.equals(A)`. Using instanceof, you can have `A instanceof B`, and `!(B instanceof A)`. This is a controversial problem though. Read more about it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks :) I was reading `Effective Java`. And have just reached that part.

Comment: @JBNizet chrs mate - i have two further questions based on your answer: (1) if one is not using a hash based collection does one still have to override a hashcode method, (2) is a List a hash based collection? chrs mate.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon 1. yes, because unless the class is private, and you don't mess up, nothing prevents it to be used in a hash-based collection later, even if it's not the case now. Why make the code fragile when it's easy to make it robust?. 2. List is an interface, so ite depends on the implementation, but I don't know (nor can imaging) any List implementation using hashCode.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to also override `hashCode` to get the behavior that you expect. The default implementation of `Object.hashCode` is probably returning the object references, although according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) this isn't required.

Without overriding `hashCode` you can't expect specialized results; this is analogous to overriding `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

You should override hashcode methode.
if a class overrides equals, it must override hashCode
when they are both overridden, equals and hashCode must use the same set of fields
if two objects are equal, then their hashCode values must be equal as well
if the object is immutable, then hashCode is a candidate for caching and lazy initialization