# is Object instance of MyClass

Tags: java, class, equals, instanceof

I need to make equals function for MyClas.

```
public class MyClass
{
boolean equals(Object value)
  {
    if (... value is type of MyCLass ...)
      {
        return= ... check conditions...;
      } else return false;
  }
}
```

For this purpose I need to know if value of Object is type of MyClass. How to make it?

Comment: it always shocks me that people care enough to answer you a full good answer but don't think the question is good enough to give upvote. +1 for good question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any reason to prefer getClass() over instanceof when generating .equals()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to check if `value` is of type `MyClass` use:

```
 if( value instanceof MyClass)
```

Comment: Not recommended:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` operator is used to determine that. It's infix, so use it like so...

```
(value instanceof MyClass)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class MyClass
    {
       boolean equals(Object value)
      {
           if (value instanceof  MyCLass)
           {
              return= ... check conditions...;
           } else return false;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
    //Your logic
```

You can also use `instanceof` instead of `getClass()` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little IDE trick. Just to save up some time.

In eclipse you can do that by right click on the class file and select source --->generate hashCode() and equals() method , select all the attribute you need to compare and IDE will generate corresponding code for you

An excerpt

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        if (salary != other.salary)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value instanceof ClassName
```

the `instanceof` key word checks, where `value`  is a `subclass` of ClassName, If yes reutns true  and otherwise  returns `false`

Answer (score 0):

Altough RTTI (*Real Time Type Identification*) is considered a code smell by some individuals, there are two alternatives, one is to use the `instanceof` operator:

```
if(value instanceof MyClass)
```

On the other hand, you can use a full fledged method from the `Class` class, that given two objects, you can determine if they belong to the same hierarchy (much more powerful than `instanceof` IMO):

```
if(value.getClass().isAsignableFrom(getClass()))
```

This second approach determines if value is the very same class or a superclass/superinterface of the current class (the `this`) at execution time given any kind of object. This is where `isAsignableFrom` excels, since with `instanceof` you need to know the reference type at compile time.