# Java .equals() instanceof subclass? Why not call superclass equals instead of making it final?

Tags: java, equals, instanceof

It is stated in Object's `.equals(Object)` javadoc:

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y,
>   x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns
>   true.

Almost everywhere in example code I see overridden `.equals(Object)` method which uses `instanceof` as one of the first tests, for example here: [What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding equals and hashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Person))
            return false;
        ...
    }
```

}

Now with `class SpecialPerson extends Person` having in `equals`:

```
        if (!(obj instanceof SpecialPerson))
            return false;
```

we con not guarantee that `.equals()` is symmetric.
It has been discussed for example here: [any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596507/2622016)

```
Person a = new Person(), b = new SpecialPerson();

a.equals(b);    //sometimes true, since b instanceof Person
b.equals(a);    //always false
```

Maybe I should add in the beginning of SpecialPerson's equals direct call to super?

```
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if( !obj instanceof SpecialPerson )
            return super.equals(obj);
        ... 
        /* more equality tests here */
    }
```

Comment: Similar problem is discussed in effective java. You can read that.

Comment: To add to Manoose comment - Effective Java sais: "The easiest way to avoid problems is not to override the equals
method, in which case each instance is equal only to itself. This is the right thing to do if any
of the following conditions apply: [...]  A superclass has already overridden equals, and the behavior inherited from
the superclass is appropriate for this class."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lot of the examples use `instanceof` for two reasons: a) it folds the null check and type check into one or b) the example is for Hibernate or some other code-rewriting framework.

The "correct" (as per the JavaDoc) solution is to use `this.getClass() == obj.getClass()`. This works for Java because classes are singletons and the VM guarantees this. If you're paranoid, you can use `this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass())` but the two are really equivalent.

This works most of the time. But sometimes, Java frameworks need to do "clever" things with the byte code. This usually means they create a subtype automatically. Since the subtype should be considered equal to the original type, `equals()` must be implemented in the "wrong" way but this doesn't matter since at runtime, the subtypes will all follow certain patterns. For example, they will do additional stuff before a setter is being called. This has no effect on the "equalness".

As you noticed, things start to get ugly when you have both cases: You really extend the base types and you mix that with automatic subtype generation. If you do that, you must make sure that you never use non-leaf types.

Comment: Can you cite the section of the documentation that is in accordance with your second paragraph?

Comment: @arshajii: It's part of the classloader contract. Standard classloaders will always return the same reference for the same class name. Bets are off for script classloaders, of course.

Comment: Oh, I meant the part "The correct solution is to use...". Are you saying it's better to compare `getClass()`s in `equals()` instead of using `instanceof`?

Comment: Yes. In general, `instanceof` in `equals()` is wrong since it could say subtypes are equal to parent types which is not always true. There was a long discussion about this in an Eclipse bug since the Hibernate guys were constantly complaining about the "missing" `instanceof` while the language purists sharpened their pitchforks.

Answer (score 1):

You are  missing something here. I will try to highlight this:

Suppose you have `Person person = new Person()` and `Person personSpecial = new SpecialPerson()` then I am sure you would not like these two objects to be equal. So, its really working as required, the equal must return false.

Moreover, symmetry specifies that the `equals()` method in both the classes must obey it at the same time. If one equals return true and other return false, then I would say the flaw is in the equals overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at solving the problem is not correct. Suppose you have 2 subclasss `SpecialPerson` and `BizarrePerson`. With this implementation, `BizarrePerson` instances could be equal to `SpecialPerson` instances. You generally don't want that.

Comment: Well there are many cases where it makes sense to have instances of two distinct subclasses be considered equal. Take `List`, for example. An `ArrayList` is and should be equal to a `LinkedList` that contains the same elements.

Comment: But then you probably don't want to override equals in subclasses, which is what this question is all about.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `instanceof`. use `this.getClass() == obj.getClass()` instead. then you are checking for this exact class.

when working with `equals`you should always use the `hashCode` and override that too!

the hashCode method for Person could look like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + age;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

and use it like this in your equals method:

```
if (this.hashCode() != obj.hashCode())
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A type should not consider itself equal to an object of any other type--even a subtype--*unless both objects derive from a common class whose contract specifies how descendants of different types should check for equality*.

For example, an abstract class `StringyThing` could encapsulate strings, and provide methods to do things like convert to a string or extract substrings, but not impose any requirements on the backing format.  One possible subtype of `StringyThing`, for example, might contain an array of `StringyThing` and encapsulate the value of the concatenation of all those strings.  Two instances of `StringyThing` would be defined as equal if conversion to strings would yield identical results, and comparison between two otherwise-indistinguishable `StringyThing` instances whose types knew nothing about each other may have to fall back on that, but `StringyThing`-derived types could include code to optimize various cases.  For example, if one `StringyThing` represents "`M` repetitions of character `ch`" and another represents "`N` repetitions of the string St", and the latter type knows about the first, it could check whether `St` contains nothing but `M/N` repetitions of the character `ch`.  Such a check would indicate whether or not the strings are equal, without having to "expand out" either one of them.