# java.util.HashMap get: does key have to be exactly the same object as what is stored in the HashMap, or can the keys just be "equal"

Tags: java, hashmap

Suppose I have a HashMap `M`.  I want to call the "get" function on this HashMap, and find the value associated with a given object `S`.  But I don't have an actual reference to the object `S`, so I create a new object `S_new` whose contents are identical to the contents of `S`.  If I call `M.get(S_new)`, will that give me the value associated with the key `S`?

Comment: absolutely no, they are not the same instance.

Comment: Short answer - it will work fine if objects are equal and have same hashCode value.

Comment: If they hash the same -- yes. If not -- no. Should it be avoided? -- Absolutely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation for Map#get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-):

> **`public V get(Object key)`**
>
> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if
>   this map contains no mapping for the key. More formally, if this map
>   contains a mapping from a key `k` to a value v such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`, then this method returns `v`; otherwise it
>   returns `null`. (There can be at most one such mapping.)

So as long as the parameter you're passing overrides `equals` in such a way that the map key is seen as equivalent, you can use a different instance to retrieve a value from a map.

Also, as @Eugene and others mentioned, for `HashMap` you must also override the `hashCode` method, and ensure that your instance returns the same value as your key. In general, best practice is to ensure that your equality implementation is *symmetric* (i.e. `A.equals(B)` <==> `B.equals(A)`), and values that are equal should have the same `hashCode`.

Comment: In a hash-based map or collection, `hashCode` must also be overridden or equality will never be tested.

Comment: The OP asked for `HashMap`, so it's important to have a matching `hashCode()` method as well.

Comment: @nbrooks if you dont override hashcode that entry might never be found at all in the context of HashMap...

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will as long as the `hashcode` and `equals` would produce the same exact values. Also notice that `get` does not even require the parameter to be `T` - it's `Object`, so `any` type that would fulfill the hashcode and equals would work

Comment: In practice, it's somewhere between unlikely and impossible that any other type would compatibly implement `equals` and `hashCode`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18575969/1953590).

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I'll agree. I have not seen a case where something other than `T` would make logical sense to get from a `Map`; still this is allowed by the spec...

Answer (score 0):

No to get value from map using key doesn't mean that key should be same object which were used while putting.

only thing is that hashcode & equals should be same  and that is the  reason its mandatory to override Hashcode & equals method if you wanna use your own class object as key .