# Java equals override

Tags: java, equals, doubly-linked-list

I intend to override the `boolean equals(Object otherObject)` method within my Pair class that utilizes a private inner class with private instance variables as follows:

```
class Pair
{
    class Node
    {
        private int x, y;
    }

    public boolean equasl(Object otherObject)
    {
        if(otherObject == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Pair other = (Pair)otherObject;

            return (x.equals(otherObject.x) && y.equals(otherObject.y));
        }
    }
}
```

It is not clear to me how I am comparing two `Pair` objects in which each object is comprised of a doubly-linked list (not shown for clarity).  Am I comparing each object beginning with the head node and traversing the lists verifying that each node in the lists are equal?

Comment: What makes you think that the Pair object has a linkedlist?

Comment: Where is the linked list in your example? I have problem understanding the question.

Comment: Because Node is a doubly-linked list I wrote but omitted the details to make presentation simple

Comment: Just small comment. You used RETURN here so you can remove if/else and else.

Answer (score 1):

The Pair class is comparing its value using equals with another pair, rather than doubly linked list. It takes the object which is a Pair object, then checks for null and classtype  and finally compares x and y values of Node class inside another pair object.

Comment: Your comment is right-on. I stumbled into the solution by adding an overridden equals method to the Node class that directly compares the x and y.  The Overridden equals in Pair directly compares Pair objects and that results in a direct comparison of their x and y when the program is run.

Comment: I had made a mistake, the x and y variables can be accessed anywhere inside the class directly, its only an error if its outside the class (doesn't matter what instance variable it is)

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume you have an instance variable `Node n` which is an instance of the inner class. I would recommend restructuring your equals method a little bit:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
 if (other == null)
  return false;
 if (! other instanceof Pair)
  return false;

 ...
}
```

Beyond that, you need to structurally compare the Node instances inside of each class. Since those are private variables on the Node, you won't be able to access them for `other`. It might be helpful to define get methods and then just compare the integers.

This is a good guide in general to overriding equals

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seas.upenn.edu%2F~cis120%2F13fa%2Flectures%2Flec32.pdf&ei=TI6jUvLTBeeysQSZxoGQCA&usg=AFQjCNFWIq0POyO5CGD7jCTbmKxlYyU5iQ&bvm=bv.57752919,d.cWc

Comment: Using `instanceof` in equals is bad practice.

Comment: I heard that instanceof in equals is bad before, but I've never find any good article about that. Can you give us a link? Thanks.

Comment: It is simple... `equals` by definition should form *equality relation*. With `instanceof` you can not guarantee that it will be *symetrical*. I will try to search for some formal article about it.

Comment: It's been discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals

Comment: Perhaps, it is, but in most cases it should be ok: http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html