# java, overriding and equals

Tags: java, equals, overriding

ok this is really a simple question but I can't understand why my code does not work properly.

In a third part library I'm using, at a certain point something like this is done:

```
Object value = someValue;
Object compareValue = someOtherValue;
if(value.equals(compareValue)) 
 // do something
```

now, my objects are instances of the same class, that override equals with the following contract:

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
```

the jvm anyway call the equals defined by the object class, giving me an unwanted behavior. 
How can I fix this?
I repeat that the calling code is an external library that i can't modify.

edit: this is the full code of my class:

```
public class MissionPriorityResolutionCriteria implements ResolutionCriteria {
private Satellite prioritySatellite;

public MissionPriorityResolutionCriteria(Satellite prioritySatellite) {
    this.prioritySatellite = prioritySatellite;
}



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 5;
    hash = 53 * hash + (this.prioritySatellite != null ? this.prioritySatellite.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final MissionPriorityResolutionCriteria other = (MissionPriorityResolutionCriteria) obj;
    if (this.prioritySatellite != other.prioritySatellite && (this.prioritySatellite == null || !this.prioritySatellite.equals(other.prioritySatellite))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public Satellite getPrioritySatellite() {
    return prioritySatellite;
}

public void setPrioritySatellite(Satellite prioritySatellite) {
    this.prioritySatellite = prioritySatellite;
}

public boolean apply(SRASolution s) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
}
```

I know that he is calling the Object.equals because I stepped with the debugger...
The equals implementation I'm using is generated by netbeans.

Comment: If you've overridden equals properly, that can't happen.

Comment: Please share your equals implementation...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java   Have you overiden it correctly?

Comment: How do you know `Object.equals()` is called? Are you certain `value` and `compareValue` are instance of your class?

Comment: it was a bulding problem. Some glitch happened with a complex mix of maven and netbeans. That means that the code that I was debugging was an outdated version that does not contain the equals method.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

it was a bulding problem. Some glitch happened with a complex mix of maven and netbeans. That means that the code that I was debugging was an outdated version that does not contain the equals method.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Override `equals` method and implement your own code. You can implement your own `equals` method using `instanceof` operator which actually check the type of instance variables are same or not. This is the code used in comparison of two strings.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
      if (anObject instanceof String) {
           String anotherString = (String)anObject;
           int n = count;
           if (n == anotherString.count) {
               char v1[] = value;
                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
                int i = offset;
               int j = anotherString.offset;
                while (n-- != 0) {
                    if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                        return false;
                }
               return true;
            }
        }
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: Checking `obj.getClass() == MyClass.class` is often better than `instanceof`, because equality needs to be symmetric: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462

Answer (score 0):

> jvm anyway call the equals defined by the object class

How did you know that the JVM called equals defined by the object class?

Assuming that is called `Object.eqauls`: Even if you have overridden equals method, an default implementation provided by IDE such as eclipse, internally gives a call to super class `equals()` method, which in your case could be `Object.eqauls`.

The IDE auto-generated code will look something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.equals(obj);
}
```

As a solution, replace the call to the `super.equals()` with your own logic for comparison.