# Java compareTo() method returns classCastException

Tags: java, compareto

Let's assume I have an Employee base class and Manager subclass which extends Employee.Now let's say I create an object x of type Employee and object y of type Manager and call `x.compareTo(y)` no exception is triggered and x and y is compared as Employees namely y is cast to an Employee but when I call `y.compareTo(x)` I get a classCastException.I need to know why this happens and how to prevent x.compareTo(y) to execute as x and y are from different classes.My idea is to use getclass() method in Reflection class like this:

```
if (getClass() != other.getClass()) 
throw new ClassCastException();
```

I also want to know is there any other way to implement this.

Comment: What do you want to compare between 2 Employees? salary? :)

Comment: @卢声远ShengyuanLu No it's just an example my code is huge couldn't post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement `compareTo()` in the class `Employee` and start it with:

```
Employee o = (Employee)other;
```

Then continue with comparing `this` to `o` - this will ensure you're comparing two `Employee`s (which is the lowest common denominator).

Answer (score 2):

here `Manager` **is a** `Employee`.

but `Employee` is not `Manager`.

Quote from Effective Java, Item 12:

Let’s go over the provisions of the compareTo contract. The first provision says that if you reverse the direction of a comparison between two object refer- ences, the expected thing happens: if the first object is less than the second, then the second must be greater than the first; if the first object is equal to the second, then the second must be equal to the first; and if the first object is greater than the second, then the second must be less than the first. The second provision says that if one object is greater than a second, and the second is greater than a third, then the first must be greater than the third. The final provision says that all objects that compare as equal must yield the same results when compared to any other object.

One consequence of these three provisions is that the equality test imposed by acompareTo method must obey the same restrictions imposed by the equals con- tract: reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity. Therefore the same caveat applies: there is no way to extend an instantiable class with a new value component while preserving the compareTo contract, unless you are willing to forgo the benefits of object-oriented abstraction (Item 8). The same workaround applies, too. If you want to add a value component to a class that implements Comparable, don’t extend it; write an unrelated class containing an instance of the first class. Then provide a “view” method that returns this instance. This frees you to implement whatever compareTo method you like on the second class, while allowing its cli- ent to view an instance of the second class as an instance of the first class when needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Payeli I am asking him to think of 'is a' relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `Manager is an Employee` but `Employee is not a Manager` See below

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

`instance of` can be usefull in such cases

Comment: Yeah I know that but I also want to stop x.compareTo(y) which executes and my idea is to use getclass() and I want to know is there anyother way to do that?

Comment: @user1613360  see alfasin answer.

Answer (score 0):

All `Manager` are `Employee` but not all `Employee` are `Managers`. Since all the attributes of `Employee` are available in `Manager`,`Manager` can be casted to `Employee`. But attributes of `Manager` is unavailable to `Employee`, so cast is not possible.

My suggestion is to override `compareTo()` method in your classes and cast the object `Employee`.

Answer (score 0):

```
If your are using compareTo method then i am excepting you have implemented Comparable interface in your class and provide a implementation of the method compareTo. let me know how you are comparing object on what logic ,based on that only you get the solution.

I have little bit confuse on this 
if (getClass() != other.getClass()) 
throw new ClassCastException();

if it is the code in your compareTo method then rather then doing this create one more interface say "XYZ" and implement that Interface to both the class
check the logic 


    public int compareTo(T obj){
    if(this instanceof XYZ &&  obj instanceof XYZ)){
return 0;
    }else{
    throw new ClassCastException();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use isAssignableFrom which will return true or false and then use it for doing further comparison or equals etc. Not sure why you would need this in compareTo; however.

Anyways assuming name , salary for an employee and set of reportees for manager and then for example further just comparing salaries as part of compareTo.

```
public class Test{   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
            public Employee(String string, int salary) {
                this.name = string;
                this.salary = salary;
            }

            public Employee() {
                name = "";
                salary = 0;
            }

            String name;
            Integer salary;

            public int compareTo(Employee o) {
                return o!=null && getClass().isAssignableFrom(Employee.class)
                        ? salary.compareTo(o.salary) : Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            }

        }

        class Manager extends Employee {
            public Manager(String name, String[] subordinates) {
                super(name, 1000000);
                reportees = subordinates;
            }

            String[] reportees;
        }

        Employee e = new Employee("me", 1000);
        Employee e1 = new Employee("mycolleague", 2000);
        Manager m = new Manager("myboss", "me mycolleague".split(" "));
        System.out.println(e1.compareTo(e));
        System.out.println(e.compareTo(m));
        System.out.println(m.compareTo(e)); // this gives INT.MIN as you cannot compare manager to employee
    }

}
```