# Which part of the equals() general contract does my equals() not satisfy

Tags: java, eclipse, equals

I'm fairly new to java and am just trying to get my head around understanding `@Override` of the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

 
I know for the equals method to be correct it needs to be:

1. **Reflexive:** `a.equals(a)`
2. **Symmetric:** `a.equals(b)` **then** `b.equals(a)`
3. **Transitive:** `a.equals(b) && b.equals(c)` **Then** `a.equals(c)`
4. **Not null:** `! a.equals(null)`

I am struggling to pinpoint which of the above properties I am and am not satisfying when writing my overide of the equals method.

*I am aware that eclipse can generate these for me, however as I haven't yet gotten the concept fully, writing it out helps me to learn.*

I have written out the what I think is the correct way to do it, but when I check with the eclipse generated version I seem to be 'missing' some aspects.

Example:

```
public class People {

    private Name first; //Invariants --> !Null, !=last
    private Name last;  // !Null, !=first
    private int age;    // !Null, ! <=0
    ...
}
```

**What I wrote:**

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (obj == null){
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof People)){
         return false;
    }
    People other = (People) obj;
    if (this.age != other.age){
        return false;
    }
    if (! this.first.equals(other.first)){
        return false;
    }
    if (! this.last.equals(other.last)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

vs **eclipse generated**

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    People other = (People) obj;
    if (first == null) {
        if (other.first != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!first.equals(other.first))
        return false; 
    if (age != other.age)
        return false;
    if (last == null) {
        if (other.last != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!last.equals(other.last))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

I am missing:

- ```
  if (this == obj)
      return true;
  ```
- ```
  if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
  ```
- *And for each variable:*

  ```
  if (first == null) {
      if (other.first != null)
          return false;
  } else if (!first.equals(other.first))
      return false;
  ```

I'm not sure what `getClass()` is and is my implmentation incorrect?

Comment: Why are you casting to `Name` in the implementation of equals for `People`? Looks like a typo. Please clarify.

Comment: You might also see [*"Any reason to prefer getClass() over instanceof when generating .equals()?"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/596462/2891664) A whole answer can be written just on that subject alone.

Comment: You still have  if (!(obj instanceof Name)){ line wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First piece of code:

```
if (this == obj)
    return true;
```

This improves performance in case you compare the object reference against itself. Example: `a.equals(a);`.

Second piece of code:

```
if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    return false;
```

This compares if the class of the reference being compared is the same class of `this`. The difference between using this approach and `instanceof` is that it's more restrictive when comparing against a sub class. Example:

```
public class Foo { }
public class Bar extends Foo { }

//...
Foo foo = new Bar();
System.out.println(foo instanceof Bar); //prints true
System.out.println(foo instanceof Foo); //prints true
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
System.out.println(foo.getClass() == foo2.getClass()); //prints false
```

Which one should you choose? There's no good or bad approach, it will depend on your desired design.

Third piece of code:

```
if (first == null) {
        if (other.first != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!first.equals(other.first))
        return false; //For each variable.
```

This is simply a null check for each object reference field in the class. Note that if `this.first` is `null` then doing `this.first.equals(...)` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: If you're wondering why the last piece doesn't use `Objects.equals`...  that part of Eclipse was probably written before `Objects.equals` was added (in Java 7).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think your implementation is incorrect, but a few notes:

> ```
> if (this == obj)
>       return true;
> ```

Is a performance optimization, it directly tests for reference equality and short-circuits tests where `a` **is** `a`.

> ```
> if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
>         return false;
> ```

Is similar to your `instanceof` call, optimizes away a null check. The other calls seem to be null-checks.

Comment: Similar, but not the same. `instanceof` is true for a subclass, which may break the "Symmetric" rule.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write

```
if (obj == null){
        return false;
}
if (!(obj instanceof People)){
     return false;
}
```

because `null` always gives `false` in `instanceof` checks. So these lines can be simplified to just

```
if (!(obj instanceof People)){
     return false;
}
```

As for your main question of whether your method meets the requirements for an `equals()` method, strictly speaking the answer is no, or at least it's potentially dodgy. This is because it would be possible to extend the class as follows

```
public class SpecialPeople extends People {

    // code omitted

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass())
            return false;
        SpecialPeople other = (SpecialPeople) object;
        return other.getAge() == getAge() 
                && other.getFirst().equals(getFirst()) 
                && other.getLast().equals(getLast());
}
```

Now suppose `a` is an instance of `People` and `b` is an instance of `SpecialPeople`. Suppose also that `a` and `b` have the same name and age. Then

```
a.equals(b) == true  // instanceof check succeeds
b.equals(a) == false // getClass() check fails
```

Therefore `equals()` is not symmetric! For this reason, if you are using `instanceof` rather than `getClass()` in `equals()` you should probably either make the `equals()` method `final` or the class `final`.

Comment: In case you use obj.getClass, you need to check for null first. Depends on the aproach you take about getClass or instanceOf