# Should i continue shortening my equals and hashcode functions?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

When i have a class like this

```
public class MyClass {
    private ClassA classA;
    private ClassB classB;
}
```

my equals and hascode function often end up in a mess like this

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((classB == null) ? 0 : classB.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((classA == null) ? 0 : classA.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
    if (classB == null) {
        if (other.classB != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!classB.equals(other.classB))
        return false;
    if (classA == null) {
        if (other.classA != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!classA.equals(other.classA))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

So i started to ignore that someone will compare apples with bananas. HashSets or HashMaps in my applications always contains the same object types... i never created a List and started mixing Integer with String.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return classB.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
    return other.classB.equals(this.classB) && other.classA.equals(this.classA);
}
```

is it bad or good practice to ignore uncommon cases and let the exceptions throw? I think it is most commonly an error when complete different classes are compared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's extremely bad practice to let `equals()` or `hashCode()` throw exceptions (I'd encourage you to read [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) for the details).

Also, your methods are unnecessarily complex. Ever since Java 7, this is pretty much the canonical way of writing these methods:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }else if (o instanceof MyClass) {
        // some will argue that the line above should have a
        // .getClass() check instead of an instanceof check.
        // those people also need to read Effective Java :-)
        MyClass that = (MyClass) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.classA, that.classA)
            && Objects.equals(this.classB, that.classB)
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(classA, classB);
}
```

Comment: Actually it's worse than bad practice as you violate the contract of equals which for instance says: " Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned and if exactly one argument is null, false is returned"

Comment: thanks for showing the state of the art writing equals+hash functions, book is ordered

Comment: Should be `&&`, not `&` perhaps?

Comment: It does, but it's not short-circuiting. That means it always evaluates both sides of the equation, even if unnecessary.

Comment: @asettouf - sorry, didn't get that. For which case would Sean's equals() implementation violate the usual contract?

Comment: @GyroGearless I don't think he's talking about my version. Comment should be on the question

Comment: @GyroGearless: It does not, I was just refering to Sean's "bad practice" part (as you break the contracts and so any other class expecting a certain behavior would probably break or have an undesirable behavior at least) My bad for the confusion.

Comment: Actually checking the classes for equality is different to instanceof unless the class in question is final.

Comment: @MarkusBenko there is some discussion of the two approaches here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/596462/342852 . Both have drawbacks, but `instanceof` is less error-prone.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Thanks for the link. It's a very interesting discussion and it's good to see that people are aware that getClass() vs instanceof makes a difference.

Answer (score -2):

It is bad practice how you shortened your `equals()` method (your `hashCode` method disregards `classA`, but there might be use cases where this is appropriate). Let me explain the problem with `equals`.

Your apparent approach is to assume that all `Objects` are of type `MyClass`. But Java is a type-safe language, so you should always define the data type you expect. Otherwise, you could simply everywhere expect `Objects` and cast them as you did in your example. That will probably work just as it does with scripting languages (e.g., Javascript) but once your code base becomes larger and multiple developers try to understand and improve your code, it becomes confusing and you loose the benefit of type-safety (e.g., to see the type-related errors during the compile time).

The other problem you are facing here is that you are using the interface of `Object`. But let's assume you define an additional (overloaded) method using the correct data type, your code would then look like this:

```
public boolean equals(MyClass other) {
    return other.classB.equals(this.classB) && other.classA.equals(this.classA);
}
```

Now you have a method that exactly does what you expect it to do, right? Not completely:

```
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
MyClass myClass2 = clone(myClass1)
myClass1.equals(myClass2) // works => true
myClass2.equals(myClass1) // the same
Object myClass3 = (Object) myClass2
myClass3.equals(myClass1) // Compares the address with the default Object.equals() => false
myClass1.equals(myClass3) // the same
```

You see that just by changing the data type, the result changes, although `myClass1`, `myClass2`, and `myClass3` are deeply equal. You will not get an exception or compilation error. Well, let's change that by actually overriding the method (just as you did).

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    MyClass other = (MyClass) obj;
    return this.equals(other); // this is the overloaded method
}
```

Now, you get a `ClassCastException` if `obj` is not of type `MyClass`. This works as long as you know how you implemented it, because there is no `Throwable` in the signature. One more thing to consider is that the `ClassCastException` extends `RuntimeException` which is unexpected for a developer (i.e., unchecked). That means if I don't know how it is implemented (e.g., because it is part of a compiled library), or even if it was you who continues the development years later and don't remember it, one may come up with something like this:

```
public class MyExtraClass extends MyClass {
    private String someIrrelevantStuff;
    // I don't want or need a separate equals
    // and assume that MyClass or Object takes care of it
}

MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
MyClass myClass2 = (MyClass) new MyExtraClass();
myClass2.equals(myClass1) // works => false
myClass1.equals(myClass2) // Throws ClassCastException
// Application crashes completely at this point
// just because I didn't expect the unchecked exception
```

I would say, this example (i.e., subclassing) is not *uncommon* or an *error*, but it fails. If you added the exception to the signature, it would be overloaded again and you are back to the point where you started. You see that there is no way out just because of the `Object`'s interface.

However, it is justified to ask if this interface is still suitable for Java in its current release version. Wouldn't it be appropriate to provide a default `deepEquals()` method instead of the current *equalsAddressOf()* (not to confuse with the current `deepEquals()` which is just applicable for arrays)? Scala already tackles this concern with its `case classes`. You may consider switching to Scala or an (optionally) unsafe language like Python if you want shorter codes.

If you really preferred a distinction of the `false` state, after all. You could simply use your own interface:

```
public abstract class DeeplyComparableObject extends Object {

    public abstract boolean deeplyEquals(Object o) throws TypeNotEqualException;
}

public class TypeNotEqualException extends Exception {

}
```

Comment: Careful: this is an overload, not an override!

Comment: That's why I removed the @Override. The overloaded method is not accessible via the Object's interface.

Comment: This isn't an `equals` method it's a method that happens to be called `equals`. Common source of insidious bugs as you have now overridden `hashCode` but not `equals` which will result is `HashMap` (for example) behaving _really_ oddly.

Comment: So you are aware that you're not overriding the `Object` method - what is the point of this method? (OP says _`HashSets` or `HashMaps` in my applications always contains the same object types_)

Comment: The point is to show that it is similarly bad to overload the method as it is bad to override without checking for all cases (datatypes).