# Java @Override equals(): When this.getClass() != o.getClass() fails but shouldn't

Tags: java, jpa

I have this @Override for *equals()* in my **MyClass** class:

```
@Entity( name = "MyClass" )
@Table( name = "my_class" )
public class MyClass extends MySuperClass
{
  ...
  @Override
  public boolean equals( Object o )
  {
    if ( this == o )
    {
      return true;
    }
    if ( o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass() )
    {
      return false;
    }
    if ( !super.equals( o ) )
    {
      return false;
    }
    MyClass that = ( MyClass ) o;
    return this.var1.equals( that.var1 ) && this.var2.equals( that.var2 );
  }
  ...
}
```

Pretty standard. Matter of fact, it follows Java best practices.
Later in life I have this in another sub-package class (my controller class):

```
...
package com.a.b.api.controllers;
...
import com.a.b.jpa.models.MyClass;
...
MyClass myObject1 = new MyClass( var1, var2 );
MyClass myObject2 = this.myClassRepository.getById( 1 ); // SpringBoot/Jpa/Hibernate

if ( myObject2.equals( myObject1 ) )
{
   ...do something...
}
...
this.myClassRepository.save( myObject1 );
...
```

My problem is that the *.equals()* is always failing here:

```
if ( o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass() )
```

because java says that *this.getClass()* and *o.getClass()* are **NOT** equal. When I debug the code (in Intellij IDEA 2022.1 UE) I see this:

> this.getClass() = MyClass@13706

but

> o.getClass = com.a.b.jpa.models.MyClass@8f7462

But they **are** the same class! Almost every Java book, tutorial, blog, Intellij IDEA, etc. demonstrates the *.equals()* this way. I have tried this in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS *java-14-openjdk-amd64* and *java-17-openjdk-amd64* with the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This, `if ( !super.equals( o ) )
    {
      return false;
    }` is new to me and doesn't really make sense. If super is Object, it falls back to checking for reference equality, which is what an equals override is being created to *avoid*.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels irrelevant as the execution never gets to that point in the code but, fyi, MyClass is extended from a super class.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, it's the same running application instance (SpringBoot 2.2.6). The code provided is almost verbatim. And, as I stated in the OP, the controller is creating a new object (to persist in the database) and loading a previous object from the database to compare.

Comment: use `!this.getClass().equals(o.getClass())` instead of `!=`

Comment: @Zircon Yep, tried it before and just tried it again. It also fails. :(

Comment: @Zircon Impossible for this to make a difference. `Class` inherits `equals` from `Object`.

Comment: `if ( o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass() )
    {
      return false;
    }` violates Liskov substitution principle. Objects are equals only if they have the same implementation class.

Comment: suggested reading https://www.baeldung.com/java-comparing-objects#equals-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***happy songs*** correctly stated in his response:

> myObject2 is an instance of a proxy class, generated at runtime by Hibernate using Byte Buddy. The generated proxy intercepts all method invocations, that's why getClass() returns different results.

I really didn't want to use *instanceof* because that is considered bad practice so I started poking around and stumbled onto a post having a similar issue. Their solution was to add the ***final*** keyword to their class declaration. I thought this insignificant but gave it try - **AND IT WORKED!** Adding the ***final*** keyword caused

```
if ( o == null || this.getClass() != o.getClass() )
```

and

```
if ( o == null || !this.getClass().equals( o.getClass() ) )
```

to work properly. My class code is now:

```
@Entity( name = "MyClass" )
@Table( name = "my_class" )
final public class MyClass extends MySuperClass
{
  ...
  @Override
  public boolean equals( Object o )
  {
    if ( this == o )
    {
      return true;
    }
    if ( o == null || !this.getClass().equals( o.getClass() ) )
    {
      return false;
    }
    if ( !super.equals( o ) )
    {
      return false;
    }
    MyClass that = ( MyClass ) o;
    return this.var1.equals( that.var1 ) && this.var2.equals( that.var2 );
  }
  ...
}
```

Thank you all for your assistance! And a big thank you to ***happy songs*** for pointing me in the proper direction!

Comment: Using instanceof is not bad practice. I think using `.getClass()` is. Note that their behavior isn't the same, because of subclassing.

Answer (score 7):

`myObject2` is an instance of a proxy class, generated at runtime by Hibernate using [Byte Buddy](https://bytebuddy.net/#/). The generated proxy intercepts all method invocations, that's why `getClass()` returns different results.

As an alternative to `getClass()`, using `instanceof` might be another approach:

```
if ( !(this instanceof MyClass && o instanceof MyClass) )
{
   return false;
}
```

However keep in mind that `instanceof` has its [drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals). It violates the symmetry principle.

You shouldn't compare these objects in the first place, since a new object should be different from a Hibernate managed one that has a persistent state.

Comment: +1 for most of this, but I think the right approach for this sort of check is to use a `canEqual` method, so that each subclass can decide whether it's equal to superclass instances. See https://www.artima.com/articles/how-to-write-an-equality-method-in-java (search within that page for `canEqual`).

Answer (score 0):

I use this standard `equals` and `hashcode` implementations for JPA entities (as described [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof MyClass)) {
        return false;
    }
    MyClass other = (MyClass) o;
    return id != null && id.equals(other.getId());
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getClass().hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a best practice.
Change your equals to be something like the following
(null check first, then same check, then class check):

```
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (obj == null) { return false; }
   if (obj == this) { return true; }
   if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
     return false;
   }
   
   ... do the actual comparison here
 }
```

Note: the code above is a paraphrase of [Apache EqualsBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html)

Comment: if ( this.getClass() != o.getClass() )     {       return false;     } violates Liskov substitution principle. Objects are equals only if they have the same implementation class.